# Can I switch the bank account associated with my Adsense account?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, youtube, payments

I'm asking because I have my youtube account tied to a family member's bank account, and I created my own bank account recently. And I wanted to switch the earnings to mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the payment address in your AdSense account by following these steps:

1. Sign in to your AdSense account.
2. Click Payments.
3. In the "Settings" section, click Manage settings.
4. In the "Payments profile" section, click Compose next to Name and address.
5. Update your payment address in the "Address" fields.
6. Click Save.

Reference: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2628816?hl=en